# How to keep value if condition is not met in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to keep a value the same until a condition is met so it changes.

I want BasinNumber to not change if conditions are not met

```
atl_cyclone_2022_update3 <- atl_cyclone_2022_update2 |>
   mutate(BasinNumberYear = case_when(
     is.na(status) ~ atl_cyclone_2022_update2$'1', 
     TRUE ~ BasinNumberYear
   )) |>
   select(BasinNumberYear, everything())
```

I tried something similar with `if_else` and using `lag`, but neither of them worked. Using `lag` only worked once and `if_else` did the exact same thing. I have tried to research similar questions but the solutions don't work for me and I keep getting the same error with

> Caused by error: ! object 'BasinNumberYear' not found

Comment: It fails in `TRUE ~ BasinNumberYear` statement in `case_when` because your dataset does not have such column named `BasinNumberYear`.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset so that we could help (use `dput(atl_cyclone_2022_update2)` for instance and post the result of the call)